# Problema al pasar datos de componente padre a hijos

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un componente padre Welcome.vue al que llego luego de hacer login, como se me hacia muy extenso el template saque el navigationDrawer y la Toolbar en dos componentes externos, algo como:

```
<template> 
   <navigation-drawer :user="user"/>
   <toolbar/>
</template>
```

El problema es que para mostrar/ocultar debo cambiar el valor de una propiedad llamada drawer: null que esta en el componente Toolbar.

```
<v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawerReverse = !drawerReverse"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
```

Al pasarla como propiedad y hacer clic me tira el error:

```
Vue warn]: Computed property "drawerReverse" was assigned to but it has no 
setter.

found in

---> <Toolbar> at src\components\layouts\Toolbar.vue
   <VApp>
     <Welcome> at src\components\Welcome.vue
       <App> at src\App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:591
sharedPropertyDefinition.set @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3493
click @ Toolbar.vue?c3d0:21
invoker @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2027
Vue.$emit @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2538
e.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:1
click @ vuetify.js?dc48:1368
invoker @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2027
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1826
```

Y no me deja mostrar/ocultar el menu, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: La propiedad originalmente estaba en `Welcome.vue` y ahora está en `NavigationDrawer.vue`? Muéstranos las propiedades computed de `Toolbar.vue`, por favor

Comment: Por el error que sale, quizas no has declarado drawerReverse en el componente Toolbar. Podrias mostrar el codigo de ese componente?